# Connect the html button to the php code to do something

Tags: php, html

I want to connect my HTML code to PHP that when you click on a specific button in a message, do these:
1- set a cookie that don't show it again.
2- hide messages with CSS.
And when user come back to my site read cookie and don't show message.

Comment: This can be done without PHP. Use local storage for that. If you need to trigger PHP script, then google for Ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are part of the HTTP requests. When you request a URL it can respond with **set-cookie** header. The browser read this and changes the cookies.

So, If you want to change a cookie, this must be done by PHP.

Let's have a button.

```
<a href='dontshowagain.php'>Dont show again</a>
```

And, PHP code,

```
setCookie("hideAnnounce", "1"); // add the cookie to response
header("location: /index.php"); // add redirection to response
```

Now, index.php can read the cookie.

```
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['hideAnnounce'])){ ?>
   <div>announcement</div>
<?php } ?>
```